# What is $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x])?$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone explain what $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ is? I just want to know what its elements look like.

In the definition, it says that for a field $K$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $M_{n}(K)$ is an algebra over $K.$

I understand what an algebra over $K$ is now.

$M_n(K) = \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ where $M_n(K)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $K^n$ to itself.

Like what is a typical element of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x])$? Is it a matrix multiplied by some complex number?

Comment: $M_n\left(K\right) = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}\left(\mathbb C\left[x\right]\right)$? How is that supposed to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a set $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ is the set of endomorphisms with domain and codomain $\mathbb{C}[x]$.  In your instance it's algebra endomorphisms.  So, it's functions $f:\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[x]$ that preserve the ring structure on $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as well as the structure of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: And such an $f$ is completely determined by where it takes $x$. Therefore $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbf C}(\mathbf C[x])$ is simply $\mathbf C[x]$ itself as a complex vector space, but with a new composition.

Comment: I would seriously discourage using $\mathrm{End}$ for algebra endomorphisms. It usually stands for module endomorphisms, whereas algebra endomorphisms normally don't warrant an extra notion (one can just write $\mathrm{Alg}\left(\mathbb C\left[x\right],\mathbb C\left[x\right]\right)$).

Comment: I often see things like $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbf{C}-\text{alg}}(\mathbf{C}[x])$, which is admittedly a pain to write down every time.

Answer (score 2):

You could think like $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$, where you matrix are indexed in the natural and add just one of the follow conditions the rows or the columns entries are almost all zero, that is only a finite number of entries are distinct from zero. Consider that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a vector space with basis $\{X^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and use the universal property of the basis.

Comment: You have to add only one of the conditions, it depends of how you define the coordinates, as a row or as column.And also dependes how notation you use for functions f(x) or (x)f.